# C++ StackOverflowException initializing struct over 63992

Tags: c++, struct, stack-overflow

"Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException" is the error I receive when I run the code below.  If I change 63993 to 63992 or smaller there are no errors.  I would like to initialize the structure to 100,000 or larger.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Point
{
    double x;
    double y;
};

int main()
{
Point dxF4struct[63993]; // if < 63992, runs fine, over, stack overflow
Point dxF4point;
vector<Point> dxF4storage;

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
dxF4point.x = i;    // arbitrary values             
dxF4point.y = i;
dxF4storage.push_back(dxF4point);
}

for (int i = 0; i < dxF4storage.size(); i++) {
    dxF4struct[i].x = dxF4storage.at(i).x;
    dxF4struct[i].y = dxF4storage.at(i).y;
}

Sleep(2000);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are simply running out of stackspace - it's not infinite, so you have to take care not to run out.

Three obvious choices:

1. Use `std::vector<Point>`
2. Use a global variable.
3. Use dynamic allocation - e.g. `Point *dxF4struct = new Point[64000]`. Don't forget to call `delete [] dxF4struct;` at the end.

I listed the above in order that I think is preferable.

[Technically, before someone else points that out, yes, you can increase the stack, but that's really just moving the problem up a level somewhere else, and if you keep going at it and putting large structures on the stack, you will run out of stack eventually no matter how large you make the stack]

Comment: Could you be more specific about choice #1?  Am I not already using std::vector<Point> in the third line of main?

Comment: I don't know why you (think) you need dxF4struct as well as a vector - I didn't write this code... My point is that if you want to store a large number of objects (Point or something else) is that you shouldn't make a large array on the stack. vector will allocate memory from the heap, and automatically deallocate it again when the vector is no longer in used [goes out of scope].

Answer (score 1):

```
Point dxF4struct[63993]; // if < 63992, runs fine, over, stack overflow
```

That line, you're allocating all your Point structs on the stack. I'm not sure the exact memory size of the stack but the default is around 1Mb. Since your struct is 16Bytes, and you're allocating 63393, you have 16bytes * 63393 > 1Mb, which causes a stackoverflow (funny posting aboot a stackoverflow on stack overflow...).

So you can either tell your environment to allocate more stack space, or allocate the object on the heap.

If you allocate your Point array on the heap, you should be able to allocate 100,000 easily (assuming this isn't running on some embedded proc with less than 1Mb of memory)

```
Point *dxF4struct = new Point[63993];
```

As a commenter wrote, it's important to know that if you "new" memory on the heap, it's your responsibility to "delete" the memory. Since this uses array `new[]`, you need to use the corresponding array `delete[]` operator. Modern C++ has a smart pointer which will help with managing the lifetime of the array.

Comment: Instead of `Point *dxF4struct = new Point[63993];`, why not `std::vector<Point> dxF4struct(63993)`?

Comment: no reason really. Just wanted to give an example of allocating on the heap explicitly.

Comment: Keep in mind that you usually will want to delete your memory after allocating it if you do it this way.  After you are done with the memory, call `delete[] dxF4struct`.  Please note `delete[]` has brackets.  Since you are deleting an array, you will need this form of `delete`.  Otherwise, I would suggest Mats Petersson's answer as using a std::vector will automate cleanup for you (and is generally considered safer because of that).

Answer (score 1):

Increase the stack size. On Linux, you can use [ulimit](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/ulimit/) to query and set the stack size. On Windows, the stack size is part of the executable and can be set during compilation.

If you do not want to change the stack size, allocate the array on the heap using the `new` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're getting a stack overflow, so the allocated stack is too small for this much data. You could probably tell your compiler to allocate more space for your executable, though just allocating it on the heap (std::vector, you're already using it) is what I would recommend.